# cmd.exe doesn't keep preferences when pinning to start menu

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, system-preferences, classic-shell

Normally, I launch cmd.exe by typing `cmd` in the Start menu and hitting Enter. I have changed the preferences of cmd such as font and color.

I searched for `cmd.exe` and pinned it to the Start menu (Classic Shell), and it shows up as `Windows Command Processor`. When I run this, my preferences are gone, and it launches with the defaults. I can change them, and it remembers them, but I have to change them in two places if I want the settings to match based on how I run the program.

I'm running the same `cmd.exe` either way. Why does it have separate preferences based on how I run it? Can I set them in a single place or unify them somehow?

Comment: The point about links which launch programs is that they are independent, so that you can have separate links to launch the same program with different parameters and initial directory. The same independence allows you to run with separate screen layouts and fonts.

Comment: Because every `.lnk` file has it's own set of properties you'll have to identify each file and then manually unify the settings. For the defaults see `reg query hkcu\console` in an open cmd window.

Comment: So where are the non-default settings for each link stored? I can see my settings in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe`, but I don't see settings for a link.